# SQL statement is empty error

Tags: mysql, jsp

I saw a lot of guides here, that says

```
if (!res.next())
```

should check if statement is empty, but when I do it I get this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /irasyti.jsp at line 73

70:     String rezervbusena=""; // rezervo busenos info
71:     String uzsakymas="";    // uzsakymas info
72:     
73:     if( !res.next()){ //jei kambariai neuzimti
74:         try {
```

I don't know what is wrong; maybe I need to import some utility? :/ my code:

```
    ResultSet res = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            //res=stmt.executeQuery
            String tas=("SELECT * from table");  
            res=stmt.executeQuery(tas);
            out.println("<br>tas: "+tas + "<br>");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("Klaida skaityme: "+ex);    
        }

    if( !res.next()){ //jei kambariai neuzimti
            try {}
               catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("error: "+ex);
        }
}
```

error was that res resultset was null and after mysql return empty statment it stays null so i had to check if its null first if(res!=null)

thank yuo all for answering

Comment: have you checked that res is not null?

Comment: What *exception* description?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the following code and see whether you are getting any errors?

```
ResultSet res = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();                        
            //res=stmt.executeQuery
            String tas=("SELECT * from table");  
            res=stmt.executeQuery(tas);
            out.println("<br>tas: "+tas + "<br>");       

    if(res.next()){ //jei kambariai neuzimti

            out.println("rs value "+rs.getString(1);
        }
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Issue-1. The *next* method returns true when that row has *data*. Issue-2. In finally block, `close()` methods throws an exception.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.irasyti_jsp._jspService(irasyti_jsp.java:164)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: @user1461771 1) Can you make sure that `SELECT * from table` returns any rows? 2) Check line number 164 in `irasyti_jsp.java`. And if possible post your full error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what *Exception* you've got but here are some explanations/tips.

Firstly you've written *Java* code in *JSPs* and it is [not consider as good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Secondly the method `boolean ResultSet.next()` returns `true` if fetched row *has* data; returns `false` otherwise.

and finally, JDBC API classes located at java.sql package so either import this package or just use classes/interfaces along with package name - `java.sql.Connection` etc.